# "Parameter Type" and "DataType" columns missing in Swashbuckle 2.1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I've upgraded my ASP.Net Core 2.0 app to include Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 2.1.0.  Prior to this, we were using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 1.0.0.  Now when I go to my swagger endpoint, I do not get the "Description", "Data Type" or "Parameter Type" columns that were displaying before.  I have looked at the swagger.json file to see if they are there, and they are.

Here's a screenshot of my new swagger UI:

[image]

And here's my old one: [image]

Are there breaking changes that are causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because it uses the latest Swagger-UI (3.x)
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master

The old one (2.x) was quite different
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/2.x

I'm sure you will find many many more differences.

But the same information is there, look closely on your screenshot, the Param Type & Data Type are under the name of the the parameter just with a smaller font.

Comment: I don't follow.  I got Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 2.1.0 from Nuget.org.  It referecnes Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI 2.1.0.  Why are you saying it references 3.x?

Comment: But more to the point... how can I get these columns to appear? I'm obviously a total newb to swagger.

Comment: That screenshot of the new one is from the 3.x version, and those columns are gone for good

Comment: But this example contains a description:  http://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/findPetsByStatus

Comment: And this one contains the data type under the column name:  http://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/uploadFile.  I just want to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: They all contain the type under the name... and Yes descriptions (if you have them will show), but your old screenshot did not have them